# How can I highlight/format e-mail addresses in an Outlook message?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

Typically, e-mail addresses in the body of incoming messages are automatically turned in to hyperlinks in Outlook. They are blue, and they are underlined.

I noticed that the e-mail addresses in the header of previous e-mails (quoted messages in the email chain) in replies from this particular vendor are turned GREEN with no underline:
[image]

Is this something that is possible to do in Outlook with a rule of some sort when replying to messages?

I really like this, and I would like to highlight e-mail addresses with our company's ORANGE color scheme. I also want to note that the e-mail addresses elsewhere in the body, such as my signature, are not changed to green. They appears as the typical underlined, blue font.

Again, this is what the e-mail addresses look like in an email chain after this company replies to me. I note that when I reply to them, Outlook doesn't do anything special to the email addresses in the previous quoted messages. They are simply black with no hyperlink:

[image]

If not done by Outlook, maybe it can be done by an Exchange transport rule? Maybe this is done by whatever MTA they use. The sender does not know how it is done. And, I can see that the mail does flow directly from their own managed MTA and not through a recognizable 3rd party service. If so, maybe this isn't the place to ask or maybe it is just not possible with standard Outlook / Exchange rules.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, I didn't find an option to change the email address format when replying to emails in outlook.
And I noticed that you want to change the format of the email address in the signature, as shown in the figure below, right?
[image]

If so, please refer to the following steps:

1.Create a new signature with the format as you want to set(New message>Message tab>Signature>Signatures…>New);
[image]

2.Click "OK";

3.Stop text from turning into a hyperlink: go to File>Options>Mail>Under Compose messages, click Editor Options>AutoCorrect Options;

4.Under AutoFormat As You Type tab, Uncheck the Internet and network paths with hyperlinks check box;
[image]

5.Under AutoFormat tab, uncheck the Internet and network paths with hyperlinks box in the Replace.
[image]

And then, the format of the email address in the signature will be displayed  in your own style. Hope to help you.

Comment: How are you doing with this issue? Is there anything you would like to update?